# Audio decode in Android Automotive

Tags: audio, decode, android-mediacodec, android-automotive, offloading

In Android Automotive OS,

Question#1) where compressed audio (ex. mp3) get decoded in generally ?

I think there is two ways.

1. Decode in Android Framework layer in MediaCodec
2. Decode in HW DSP (I mean, audio dedicated firmware)

As I guess, in mobile, OEM prefer 2) option. b/c they want to reduce power consumption.
But, in Autotmotive, power consumption does not matter anymore.
So, what is general way to support decoding mp3 ??

Searched Android document

Expecting what is general way to support audio decoding

Comment: It is not only power, it is also remove work from CPU, since decoding is a task that can block the cpu. You can choose what decoder you want, hardware or software.